# Leibniz's theorem to find nth derivatives

Tags: calculus

The question is to find the $n$th derivative of $f(x) = (e^{2x})/x$

So what I've done so far is work out derivatives of  and

Which are:
$$\begin{align*}
u &= x^{-1},& v &= e^{2x},\\
 u' &= -(x^{-2}),&  v' &= 2e^{2x},\\
 u'' &= 2x^{-3}, & v'' &= 4e^{2x},\\
 u''' &= -6x^{-4}& v''' &= 8e^{2x},\\
&\vdots&&\vdots\\
u^{(n)} &= (-1)^{n}(n!)x^{-(n+1)}. &v^{(n)} &= 2^{n}e^{2x}.\end{align*}$$

And then plugging this into the Theorem you get:

$$x^{-1}(2^{n}e^{2x})) + ((n!/(n-1)!)(-x^{-2})2e^{2x})+\cdots + ((-1)^{n}(n!)x^{-(n+1)}e^{2x}) $$

My question is... have I done this right? Is this the sort of answer I'm looking for? Should i display more terms? There doesn't seem to be a pattern or anything of the like.

Comment: Unless incomplete gamma functions are part of your repertoire, you can't get anything simpler than $2^n\frac{e^{2x}}{x}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(-\frac12\right)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{k!}{x^k}$...

Answer (score 4):

Try rewriting the equation as $xy = e^{2x}$ and then repeatedly differenting both sides. Incidentally, old calculus texts (which are usually freely available at google-books) are a good source for this topic. An especially good treatment is given in Articles 56-58 (pages 64-73) of the following book. In particular, see Exercises 2 and 3 in Article 57 (p. 70).

**An Elementary Text-Book on the Differential and Integral Calculus** by William Holding Echols (1902)

http://books.google.com/books?id=efoKAAAAYAAJ

Comment: Perhaps not the best link?

Comment: @AD. Clicking on the book cover photo takes you to a page where page numbers can be inserted (push "Enter" after typing in the desired page number), plus a pull-down menu there allows access to the various chapters (and gives their page ranges). Of course, the .pdf file can simply be downloaded. Finally, a URL for a specific page 'kmn' can be obtained by sticking '&pg=PAkmn' at the end of the "initial URL" that I gave. Thus, click on the URL I gave and then paste '&pg=PA70' (without quotes) at the end of it where it appears in your internet browser window, then push "Enter".

Comment: I'm not sure what could be suboptimal about the URL I gave, but it occurred to me just now that perhaps some books digitized by google and freely available in the U.S. might not be accessible in some other countries. With that in mind, here's another link to the Echols book: http://www.archive.org/details/anelementarytex00echogoog

Comment: Thanks Dave, yes that is probably the case.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes haha , 3 years later and it is still not available here . EDIT: It seems that it is not available even in US now

Comment: @A Googler: I just checked and didn't have a problem getting it from google-books. Maybe you have to have a google account? Anyway, I downloaded it to see how big the file is, and it's 10.3 MB, which is within what I think I'm able to send by email where I'm at (it's certainly within what Yahoo mail lets you send, but I have additional constraints), so if you want a copy, send me an email to my Yahoo email (at my math stackexchange profile) and I'll send you the .pdf file.